# NodeJS ssl connection to mongodb server freezes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have setup my own mongodb server and I am using SSL to successfully connect to it:

```
mongo --ssl --sslCAFile ~/.ssl/hostname.ca-bundle --sslPEMKeyFile ~/.ssl/mongo.pem -u superadmin -p --host hostname --authenticationDatabase admin
```

My following nodejs code never finishes, no error is emmited

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const fs = require('fs');

const ca = [fs.readFileSync("~/.ssl/hostname.ca-bundle")];
const cert = fs.readFileSync("~/.ssl/mongo.pem");

const url = 'mongodb://superadmin:password@hostname:27017/test?authSource=admin&ssl=true"';

MongoClient.connect(url, {
    server: {
        sslValidate: true,
        sslCA: ca,
        sslCert: cert,
}
}, function (err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    client.close();
});
```

I went through the mongodb dopcumentation up and down, but so far I was not able to find what I am doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.